# How do I extract the width of .main in CSS

Tags: css

I want to create an element in css and keep it at a constant right spacing from the main content.

for example:-

```
.main
{
    padding: 0px 12px;
    margin: 12px 8px 8px 8px;
    min-height: 420px;
    width: 924px;
    height: 580px;
}
```

now I am creating an image that needs to be at a constant distance from the main content, and on its right hand side.

ie. say 100px from main content at all times, no matter the size of window:-

```
    .NewElement {
    width: 78px;
    height: 70px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 550px;
    right: .main.width() + 100px;  <--- how do I represent this??
    display: none;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    background: url('../xxx.png') no-repeat;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

right: .main.width() + 100px;  <--- how do I represent this correctly??

Comment: if you used position: fixed; it will keep the element fixed no matter how you resize the window.

Comment: Where will be .NewElement located?

Comment: @Keith but I am noticing, if I am restoring the size of the browser, then the element falls on the .main part of my window. I want it outside the .main part of my window, on the right hand side by 100 px.

Answer (score 2):

Place 'NewElement' within the 'main' DIV (assuming these are DIVs) and set the margin-left:100px, so it will always be relative to that main DIV.

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="NewElement"></div>
</div>
```

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/w2Tm7/) a fiddle.

Comment: very cool Poornima, margin-left is a new thing that I learned from your snippet. Thanks.

Comment: however the problem still remains, if I use the browser on a 22inch monitor my margin-left:950px;

is not the same as when I open it in a browser on a 16inch monitor.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use javascript or jquery to do this:

```
var width = $('.main').css('width');
$('.NewElement').css('width',width+100);
```

Comment: yes, but I was looking for something in css. the jquery part, I already know that. I am not trying to just get a quick answer, rather learn how to do what my question specifically says, if that is possible.